# kafka consumer rebalancing in case of manual/assigned partitioning

Tags: apache-kafka

I have some doubt regarding rebalancing. Right now, I am manually assigning partition to consumer. So as per docs, there will no rebalancing in case consumer leave/crashed in a consumer groups.

Let's say there are 3 partition and 3 consumers in same group and each partition is manually assigned to each consumer. And after some time, the 3rd consumer went down. Since there is no rebalancing, what all measures I can take to ensure minimum downtime?
Do I need to change config of any of the 1st two partition to start consuming from 3rd partition or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know why would you assign partitions to consumers manually?

I think you need to write rebalanceListener. https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/ConsumerRebalanceListener.html

My advice: just let kafka decide which consumer will listen to which partition and you would not have to worry about this.

Comment: can we get how many partitions are allotted consumers in case of manual assignment(done by someone else)?

Answer (score 0):

Although there might be context that would make the approach valid, as written, I question your approach a little bit.

The best way to ensure minimum downtime is to let the kafka brokers and zookeeper do what they're good at, managing your workload (partitions) among your consumers, which includes reassigning partitions when a consumer goes down.

Your best path is likely to use the OnPartitionsRevoked and OnpartitionsAssigned events to handle whatever logic you need to be able to assume a new partition (see JRs link for more-details information on these events).

I'll describe a recent use-case I've had, in the hope it is relevant to your use-case. 
I recently had 5 consumers that required an in-memory cache of 50 million objects.  Without partitioning, each consumer had its own cache, resulting in 250 mil objects.
To reduce that number to the original 50 million, we could use the onpartitionsrevoked event to clear the cache and the onassigned to repopulate the cache with the relevant cache for the assigned partitions.

Short of using those two handlers, if you really want to manually assign your partitions, you're going to have to do all of the orchestration yourself:

1. Something to monitor if one of the other consumers is down
2. Something to pick up the dead consumer's partition and process it
3. Orchestrate communication between the consumers to communicate when the dead consumer is alive again, so it can start working again.

As you can probably tell from the list, you're in for a real world of hurt if you force yourself down that path, and you probably won't do a better job than the kafka brokers - there's an entire business whose entire focus focus is developing and maintaining kafka so you don't have to handle all of that complexity.

Comment: can we get how many partitions are allotted consumers and how many are left?